# Install on MacBook Pro 16" (2019)

Tags: system-installation, macbook

Hi there I followed the instructions to make am install drive on a USB stick using Etcher. Had no problems creating however when I attempt to boot (I'm on OS X 11.2.1 Big Sur) and Elementary doesn't boot up. I see two EFI disks, neither of which boot. Is there anything else I can try, the instructions mention burning a disk which seems quite outdated, who actually uses a DVD burner anymore?

Thanks for the kind help and suggestions!

Comment: I'm curious as to whether or not you will dual boot?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux) you can find the most recent state of Macbook support under linux.

Your model, according to [Apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201300) is MacBookPro16,1 or MacBookPro16,4.

Supossing your model is MacBookPro16,1. On the github site it specifies:

> The MacBookPro16,1 currently requires a 5.6-RC kernel and the latest amdgpu drivers.

So I think the issue is that you don't get screen output. Possible solutions involve installing this amdgpu driver manually and updating to a mainline kernel.

Try to boot into any elementary option and press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to open a tty ( console view). Login with your user credentials ( login = your username) and execute `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. The root password is the same as your password usually.

To install the required kernel, the easiest way is to reboot and do it manually.

Go to the [mainline 5.6-RC website](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.6-rc7/) and download from the AMD64 version the debs in the 1st, 2nd, 4th,and 6th line (the generic versions basically). Then install all of them with `sudo apt install ./li*.deb`. Make sure you open a terminal in the same folder as your files.

For any other issue please refer to the linked github site.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic info, I'll give my 16,1 MacBook a test and see if I can get it up and running.